# vue NOT re render with data change

Tags: vue.js

Vue renders `v-if=true`. But if I change bool true **to false**,
**vue doesn't re-render to v-else div.**

How should it be? Is there any way to re-render?

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="bool">
        true
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        false // if button pressed, i should be shown!!!!
    </div>
    <button :click='onClickEvent()'>click!!!!!!</button>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                bool: true
            };
        },
        created() {
            
        },
        mounted(){
        
        }
        methods: {
            onClickEvent: function(){
                this.bool= false
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

I tried everything I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be binding with `:click` instead it should be `@click="onClickEvent"`.

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html

Comment: Since no arguments are passed to the handler, there is no need to use [inline handler style](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#calling-methods-in-inline-handlers) here. Instead, you'd go for `@click="onClickEvent"`

Comment: @UliKrause I updated the answer to reflect this, thank you!